# Selecting alias column in Spring Boot Application using MyBatis Sql Query

Tags: java, spring-boot, sybase, mybatis

I'm working on Spring Boot Application using Maven and I'm using Sybase database and MyBatis as ORM framework.

I need to execute query like:

```
SELECT M.COL_A, M.COL_B, M.COL_C FROM MY_TABLE M 
UNION
SELECT N.COL_A, N.COL_B, "" AS COL_C FROM MY_TABLE2 N;
```

Now `MY_TABLE2` does not have `COL_C` column but I need to select it for union clause to work.

This query works fine as my database but gives me following error when executed via MyBatis:

```
com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: Invalid column name ''.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application connection appears to be running with quoted_identifier enabled.

For example, switching out your table names for a couple system tables:

```
set quoted_identifier on
SELECT M.id, M.name, M.crdate FROM sysobjects M
UNION
SELECT N.id, N.name, "" AS COL_C FROM syscolumns N
go

Msg 207, Level 16, State 4:
Server 'ASE201', Line 2:
Invalid column name ''.
```

You can try disabling quoted_identifier in your application's connection (sorry, no idea how/where you'd do that in your application), or replace the double quotes with single quotes, eg:

```
set quoted_identifier on
SELECT M.id, M.name, M.crdate FROM sysobjects M
UNION
SELECT N.id, N.name, '' AS COL_C FROM syscolumns N
go

 id      name            crdate
 ------- --------------- -------------------
       1 sysobjects      May 31 2016 12:55PM
       2 sysindexes      May 31 2016 12:55PM
       3 syscolumns      May 31 2016 12:55PM
       4 systypes        May 31 2016 12:55PM
       8 syslogs         May 31 2016 12:55PM
... snip ...
```

Comment: @SuhasBadhe; great; if there are no other issues/concerns I recommend you mark the question as answered